# Difference between ! vs !! vs * in /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, passwd, shadow

The second field in the Linux `/etc/shadow` file represents a password. However, what we have seen is that:

1. Some of the password fields may have a single exclamation

   ```
   <account>:!:.....
   ```
2. Some of the password fields may have a double exclamation

   ```
   <account>:!!:.....
   ```
3. Some of the password fields may have an asterisk sign

   ```
   <account>:*:.....
   ```

By some research on internet and through [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2026413), I can understand that `*` means password never established, `!` means locked.

Can someone explain what does double exclamation (`!!`) mean? and how is it different from (`!`)?

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Hi Muru, am new to Unix and trying to create a script which will run on RHEL 6.6 and HP-UX B.11.23

Comment: "By convention, accounts that are not intended to be logged in to (e.g. bin, daemon, sshd) only contain a single asterisk in the password field. Note that there is nothing special about ‘*’, it is just one of many characters that cannot occur in a valid encrypted password (see crypt(3))." --[OpenBSD man page for passwd(5)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/master.passwd.5?query=passwd&sec=5).  I would expect ! or !! to be no different, technically, regarding whether it is a valid passwd file, or regarding logins.  However, some tools might have special support.

Comment: Don't use the BSDs' doco as references for this.  Their accounts database handles things differently and does not even have an `/etc/shadow` file.  [Don't put answers into comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/), either.  ☺

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Both "!" and "!!" being present in the password field mean it is not possible to login to the account using a password.

As it can be [read from the documentation of RHEL-4](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/System_Administration_Guide/s2-redhat-config-users-process.html), the "!!" in the shadow-password field means the account of a user has been created, but not yet given a password. The documentation states (possibly erroneously) that until being given an initial password by a sysadmin, it is locked by default.

However, as others have noted, and as the man pages indicate for later versions of RHEL-7, it is possible a user may still log on to the account through other means, such as via SSH using public/private key authentication.

Comment: This maybe true on Red Hat systems, but not necessarily elsewhere - on Ubuntu or Arch Linux, a newly-created account with no password still has only `!`, not `!!`.

Comment: True indeed that I have never seen a "!!" in a Debian system. I would guess the OP is using some RH-based system, or SuSE.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers, would the above explanation provided by Rui - hold good for an hp-ux as well?

Comment: @JavaTec Not necessarily: I think all unices that have a `/etc/shadow` have the same field but how the password field stores non-password information varies. Check the HP-UX documentation, starting with the `shadow` man page.

Comment: Indeed it can vary by Unix versions and even in the same variant by command eg. adduser vs usermod and others.

Comment: HP-UX did not even have `/etc/shadow` until relatively recently: before HP-UX 11.11, the options were either classic shadowless `/etc/passwd` or  "Trusted Computing Base", that stored each user's password hashes and other account information in individual files named `/tcb/files/auth/<initial>/<username>`, readable only by root. In HP-UX 11.11, `/etc/shadow` was introduced as an [optional extra](https://h20392.www2.hpe.com/portal/swdepot/displayProductInfo.do?productNumber=ShadowPassword), in 11.23 it was an option in the base OS, and in 11.31 the TCB was finally deprecated.

Comment: It is worth noting that an account is not actually locked in this way, it only means the user cannot use a password to authenticate and probably cannot set a password. I have tested this on both Debian and EL based distributions: login with ssh key still works with either "!" or "!!" in the password field.

Comment: @Roy What you note is partially true. If `sshd` is configured for password based authentication (`PasswordAuthentication Yes`) **OR** challenge response authentication (`ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes`), then `sshd` considers the accounts with `!!` in the 2nd field of `/etc/shadow` locked.

Comment: The `!!` have probably less magic than thought. With Ansible e.g., if the user is created with a `!` in the password field and the `password_lock` field set to `yes` it puts a `!` in front of the existing password thus rendering it `!!`. So maybe it comes from some tool not doing it correctly...

Comment: @HolgerBöhnke Maybe it comes to a tool, maybe changes over the years. This answer is from 2015.

Comment: The answer does not clarify `*`

Answer (score 11):

It may also be worth noting `<account>::.....` meaning that there is no password required (empty password).

If you are creating an ssh **key-only** user you could use `<account>::0:0:99999:7:::` to require that the user set their password (i.e. that they use for sudo) on their first login.

*Note*: **key-only** authentication means that a password is *NOT* an authentication factor.

Comment: Beware of this. An empty field means there is no password, and you just have to press ENTER to login, at least in the console.

Comment: From `man shadow` regarding encrypted password field: "This field may be empty, in which case no passwords are required to authenticate as the specified login name." <-- Leaving this field emtpy results in open account and this should indeed be avoided!

Comment: Note that many SSH implementations block login on null passworded accounts by default: `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T| grep empty` would return: "permitemptypasswords no"

Comment: Changed the answer to clarify that I meant key-only login.

Comment: Another note, why one should never use empty passwords. Think about what happens if you install any software that uses "linux-authentication"? E.g. phpMyAdmin would than allow logins without a password. This can be very dangerous. And key only users should have "!"